# centering caption not working properly with justification=centering

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

The following caption does not look centered properly (but I still want the table to span over the full text width so that the table does not enter within the right margin).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$s$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$r$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$t$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$u$} \\
\cline{2-5}
{$s$} & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ \\
\cline{2-5}
{$r$} & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ \\
\cline{2-5}
{$t$} & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ \\
\cline{2-5}
{$u$} & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ \\
\cline{2-5}
\end{tabularx}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Parametrised glue matrix for any gorge constraint}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use `tabularx` like this! `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|c|c|c|c|}` without an X column tabularx has no way to achieve the stated `\textwidth`

Answer (score 2):

Probably you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

Your caption is centered regarding text width, however position of table looks as it is shifted left. This is consequence of use `tabularx` (see David Carlisle comment above). By use of `tabular` instead `tabularx` you will obtain above image of table:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$}|*{4}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$s$} 
               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$r$} 
                            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$t$} 
                                         & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$u$}\\
\cline{2-5}
s & 1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890 \\
\cline{2-5}
r & 1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890 \\
\cline{2-5}
t & 1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890 \\
\cline{2-5}
u & 1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890 \\
\cline{2-5}
\end{tabular}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Parametrised glue matrix for any gorge constraint}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, in above MWE I slightly optimize your code in MWE.

Comment: @Mico, yes. I forgot to add math mode to this column. I will correct this.

Answer (score 1):

To use a `tabularx` environment with a pre-set width (here: `\textwidth`), you *must* use the `X` column type -- either directly or in some suitably modified form. In the example below, I define `C` as a centered version of `X` and use it for 4 of the 5 columns; only the first column is assigned type `c`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{caption,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}   % centered 'X' column
\newcolumntype{D}{>{$}c<{$}}       % automatic math-mode centered column
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}D@{}}{#1}}   % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\captionsetup{justification=Centering}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} D|C|C|C|C| }
\mc{} & \mc{s} & \mc{r} & \mc{t} & \mc{u} \\
\cline{2-5}
s & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ \\
\cline{2-5}
r & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ \\
\cline{2-5}
t & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ \\
\cline{2-5}
u & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ & $1234567890$ \\
\cline{2-5}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Parametrised glue matrix for any gorge constraint}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```